# Get user's email in FBConnect iphone sdk

Tags: email, facebook-graph-api, graph, fbconnect

do you know how to get in fbconnect the user email for iphone sdk?
I get uid, name and sex. But I can't get the email.

- (void)session:(FBSession *)session didLogin:(FBUID)uid {
  NSString *fql=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"select uid,name,sex,email,birthday from user where uid == %lld", uid];

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/guides/mobile/ here I don't see a solution. 
thanks

Answer (score 0):

The user needs to authorize the app to get the email.

Answer (score 0):

In order to fetch user's email address, facebook requires developers to request "email" permission from the user and if the user grants the permission, you'll be able to fetch their email address.

There's a detailed documentation about the various types of permissions that your app can request from the user which enables your app to either read or write certain information on the user's behalf. Have a look: 
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/permissions/